# Embedded device, once seen on code project and can't remember the manufacturer

Tags: frameworks, embedded, motherboard

The article was about an embedded device containing a memory chip, processor and could be extended with bluetooth wifi and an other RF transmitter. 
The manufacturer developed a framework which contained: memory managment, TCP/IP stacks and more.

Anyone has an idea what it was?
thnx

Comment: Just remembered, one part was called Bee something I believe (I think the bluetooth component)

Answer (score 0):

ZigBee was partially correct =)

The wireless module was from ZigBee (XBee), the company I ment was Arduino =)

Took me allot of digging but I found it, thnx for you input =D